# "about" is omitted from comment formatting page

Tags: feature-request, comments, magic-links

The [comment formatting page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) omits the shortcut `[about]`, which is equivalent to `[tour]`:

> [image: [tour] entry on comment formatting page]

Could it be added to the list item for `[tour]` please?

Comment: Does '*How to Ask*' work? [how-to-ask] **Edit:** Nope, can that be added too?

Comment: @Script47 It's `[ask]`: [ask]

Comment: Many things are omitted from that list. For the complete list, see [Complete list of help center magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/369403). It's considered _legacy_ there.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @ErikvonAsmuth. I didn't know about that. In fact, I had only just recently discovered the link in my question. However, there does not appear to be an "Ask a new question" shortcut, for example `[new]`, which point to the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page. This would be extremely useful in shortening comments to new users. I think that I might put a feature request in on Meta - does that sound like a good idea?

Comment: @Greenonline You could try it, but I doubt it'd get much support. If you can make a good use case for it (why it's needed) you can of course give it a shot, but MSE is a tough crowd for feature requests. You'd have to explain them investing hours of development time and testing for saving some users about a minute.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Hours of development time to add to a functionality that already exists as simple as that? Dang... No wonder everything takes 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton If you let every developer just spend 10 minutes on tasks that can be developed in 10 minutes, and you have 5 developers working full-time, you risk getting software with a ridiculous amount of interfering features, many bugs and deployment issues, etc. Enterprise software is a strange game.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I agree with you, but I doubt this feature would take even 10 minutes to implement, and would have an extremely low risk of "interfering", considering how trivial the feature is, and considering the feature itself already exists. It definitely doesn't hurt developers to _sometimes_ spend time on smaller issues/feature requests such as this one which would only take a couple of minutes. I'm not saying all the developers should spend a lot of time on small projects all the time though. With that said, I agree with you that this feature wouldn't get much support and (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) probably wouldn't be added to SE, especially since there are already several of these "magic links" that no one has ever used. ([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/886489/magic-link-usage-in-comments-by-users?DaysBack=30#resultSets))